# What does "finitely many" mean here? "$B$ is a collection of sets that are the intersection of finitely many sets in [a set of sets]"

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Take a set of sets $C$. What does it mean when we say

> "$B$ is a collection of sets that are the intersection of *finitely many* sets in $C$?"

Does "finitely many" mean "from 1 to n"?

With $1$, I mean the intersection of a set with itself.

Comment: It means that the number is not infinite.

Comment: "Every natural number has only finitely many divisors", how do you understand this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that for every set $D\in B$ there is a natural number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and a collection of sets $\lbrace C_1,\dots, C_n\rbrace\subset C$ so that $D=\bigcap_{j=1}^n C_j$

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks

Comment: Then, n can be equal to 1 in your definition

Comment: @VahidM.SafarZadeh Yes. So any element of $C$ is a valid element of $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Let it be that $X$ is a set and that $\mathcal C\subseteq\wp(X)$, i.e. $\mathcal C$ is a collection of subsets of $X$.

Then we can define $\mathcal B$ as the collection of sets that can can all be written as an intersection of finitely many sets.

In mathematical notation:$$\mathcal{B}:=\left\{ \bigcap\mathcal{D}\mid\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{C}\text{ and }\mathcal{D}\text{ is finite}\right\}$$

Here: $$x\in\bigcap\mathcal{D}\iff\forall D\;\left[D\in\mathcal{D}\implies x\in D\right]$$
or more shortly: $$x\in\bigcap\mathcal{D}\iff\forall D\in\mathcal{D}\;\left[x\in D\right]\tag1$$

---

Special case $1$: $\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$
a singleton.

That means that $D=\left\{ D\right\} $ for some $D\in\mathcal{C}$
and applying $\left(1\right)$ we find easily that $\bigcap\left\{ D\right\} =D$.

This actually tells us that:$$\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal B$$because for every $D\in\mathcal C$ we have $D=\bigcap\left\{ D\right\}\in\mathcal B$.

---

Special case $2$: $\mathcal{D}=\varnothing$

For every $x$ it
is vacuously true that $\forall D\in\varnothing\;\left[x\in D\right]$.

Also if $x\notin X$ so it is somehow "running out of hand".

In this case often a convention is applied that says that we only
restrict to elements in the original set $X$ leading to:$$\bigcap\varnothing=X$$

So under this definition of $\mathcal B$ and this convention we always have: $$X\in\mathcal{B}$$